# PHP Warning running EE2.6.1 on MAMP (not Pro)

Tags: php-errors

I'm getting the following PHP Warnings being generated when running a dev site on my local machine. I'm using MAMP (not the Pro version)

I have no add-ons installed.

The only 'non-standard' thing is that I'm using CodeKit and the EE files are part of my project in CodeKit - could CodeKit have 'mangled' something (though I don't know why it would)?

Any ideas what this means and what is causing it?

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: file_get_contents(/Volumes/Websites/CLIENT/JOBNAME/dev/system/expressionengine/cache/ee_version/current_version): failed to open stream: Device not configured
Filename: helpers/file_helper.php
Line Number: 48
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Volumes/Websites/CLIENT/JOBNAME/dev/system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)
Filename: core/Common.php
Line Number: 412
```

UPDATE: Forget this. The problem seems to be with the Xserve from which the file is running apparently changing file permissions of its own accord. I got it working, then after a few minutes it stopped and all I was doing was splitting an HTML file and creating a few embeds! I've given up trying to work out why and simply moved the whole lot to a local drive where it seems much happier!

Comment: Volumes? Where is your mamp htdocs type folder on your mac?

Comment: It was on a remote volume served via an Xserve. I seem to have fixed the problem now. Restarted my Mac and also adjusted the perms on the parent directory via the server. Not sure which fixed it. Oddly it was working fine yesterday.

Comment: See, told you it was a problem with that volumes bit....

Comment: Actually it broke again shortly after it started working... for absolutely no obvious reason. Almost as if the server decided to change the file perms on its own. I have relented and moved the whole lot to my local drive where it seems much happier.